# Filtered the last user tweets with TwitterStream

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I have created a twitterStream in twitter4j java Api, with which I want to track down user's status. I got a list of users which is actually the followIDs.  In listener actually I download user's status images. I save my images with the following name:

```
String ImageUniqueFileName = status.getUser().getId()+"_id_"+CreateUniqueFileName();
ImageUniqueFileName = ImageUniqueFileName + ".jpg";
```

I ve noticed that in saved images, I got several user ids which was not in the initial list followIDs. Is it normal that I track down ids from other users? Second question, how is it possible to track down not all user tweets but just the last 200 user tweets in twitterStream?

```
TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
twitterStream.addListener(listener);

FilterQuery fq = new FilterQuery();
// fq.track(myQueries);
fq.follow(followIDs);
twitterStream.filter(fq);     
ArrayList<FilterQuery>  list = new ArrayList<FilterQuery>();
list.add(fq);
```

Comment: Were you doing `track` and `follow` at the same time? (I see that `track` is currently commented out).

Comment: I ve to do both track and follow? I am not sure that I exactly understand what I ve got to do.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I was asking if you used `track` and then `follow` or if you were doing `track` and `follow` at the same time.

Comment: I am using only follow with follwIDS a list of user ids.

Comment: Ok. I was just asking because if you use both together it means "filter Tweets with these keywords or from these users". It doesn't look like that's your problem though. :-)

Comment: Basically I am guessing that the returned unknown ids are users that retweets from my known listed ids. Its just a guessing thought, I couldn't make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `follow` parameter will result in the following Tweets being matched:

> - Tweets created by the user.
> - Tweets which are retweeted by the user.
> - Replies to any Tweet created by the user.
> - Retweets of any Tweet created by the user.
> - Manual replies, created without pressing a reply button (e.g. “@twitterapi I agree”).
>
> *[source](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters#follow)*

I think you assumption is correct, this may account for the unknown ids.

Regarding obtaining the user's Tweets, you won't be able to use the streaming api for that as it's a real time view of Twitter. However, you may be able to use [`getUserTimeline(userId, paging)`](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/TimelinesResources.html#getUserTimeline%28long,%20twitter4j.Paging%29) to retrieve the Tweets.

For a simple example of `getUserTimeline` in action, take a look at the [`GetUserTimeline` example](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples/timeline/GetUserTimeline.java).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jonathan. The crucial part of my initial question is how I could possible returned the last 100 tweets of user.

Comment: My bad, I completely glossed over that.